# Troubleshooting Airflow Deployment on Kubernetes: Webserver Inaccessibility, Pod Crashes, and Timeout Issues

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, kubernetes-helm, kind

I'm currently working on deploying Apache Airflow on a Kubernetes cluster using the official helm chart, but I'm encountering several issues throughout the deployment process.

The Airflow webserver becomes inaccessible intermittently.
Pods, including various Airflow components, crash sporadically.
Deployment often takes an excessively long time, eventually resulting in timeouts due to conditions not being met.

I've attempted deployment using different methods, including deploying it on kind, but the problems persist. Could someone provide insights into what might be causing these issues? Additionally, if there are any relevant documentation, tutorials, or best practices that could assist in troubleshooting and resolving these problems, I would greatly appreciate any pointers.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: I would start with pods events and logs...